# Change the color of single rows of a Bootstrap striped table

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I wan't to change the color of individual rows of an striped table by using JQuery:

```
$("#rowElementId").addClass("activeRow");
```

The css class `activeRow` looks like this:

```
.activeRow {
background-color: #d9d9d9;
}
```

The table itself looks like this:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr id=...>
        ...
```

The problem is, that my solution, the JQuery instruction, only works for the white rows of the striped table. How can I change this?

Here you can find an example of my problem: [Bootstrap](http://www.bootply.com/gRNTvBnWTj)

Comment: Any chance you can set up a Bootply (http://www.bootply.com/) or jsFiddle example? Description is good, working example is better

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/gRNTvBnWTj

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Specificity is off.  The current row color selector is the following in bootstrap 3: `.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-of-type(odd)`.

You should make your style this to increase its specificity:

```
.table-striped>tbody>tr.activeRow{
    background-color: #d9d9d9;
}
```

Edit: [here is a fork of your bootply](http://www.bootply.com/lXrkJvbMm7) demonstrating this method.  (I've added extra rows for clarity)

Answer (score 1):

try to add `!important` to your rule, like

```
.activeRow {
  background-color: #d9d9d9 !important;
}
```

Comment: This "works", but usually I wouldn't recommend messing with the `!important` rule unless you know it won't cause any problems.